# При выборе опции - свернуть список и отобразить выбранный элемент

Tags: jquery, list, dropdown

Нужно что бы при выборе одного элемента из  списка сам список сворачивался, а элемент стал на место `<span>`.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
      $("li").toggle(300);
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrappeerDropdown">
    <ul>
      <span class="dropdown">Select</span>
      <li>
        <a>Max</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Rex</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Wex</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Извините, но я просто не знаю и не нашел как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list li').click(function() {
     $('.dropdown').html($(this).text());
      $(".list").toggle(300);
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrappeerDropdown">
   <span class="dropdown">Select</span>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <a>Max</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Rex</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Wex</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Работает хорошо, но изначально у меня список идёт в свёрнутом виде. Не могли бы вы мне объяснить как его развернуть что бы при этом работал ваш код?

Comment: @Mbmenes при таком раскладе пользователь должен сделать два действия, первым нажать на что то для открытия списка, вторым нажатием уже на конкретную строку - закрыть ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я уже сделал сам)Вы правы, я написал функцию для открытия списка  всё отлично.